# If unsubscribe an Email address in Gmail, how to subscribe again?

Tags: gmail

For example, if unsubscribe like this, then won't receive emails from offers@email-od.com(a member email address in Google groups).

How to subscribe again if still want to receive from this email address?

After I check the Google groups members, I found the the member still there.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Legitimate Distribution Lists

An email message from a reputable distribution list that follows current best practices will include at a minimum:

1. The reason the recipient is receiving the message. ie. The justification for the message not being spam.
2. Instructions and/or a link by which the recipient can unsubscribe.

#### Gmail-Generated Unsubscribe Link

If Gmail is able to properly identify an unsubscribe link in the email it will  highlight it by adding an additional unsubscribe link at the top of the message.

This simplifies unsubscribing for Gmail users as they don't need to search for the sender-provided link in the message or scroll to the fine print at the end where it is often located.

Gmail doesn't unsubscribe you from the list, just highlights the sender-provided mechanism and what the link actually does is dependent on the functionality provided by the sender.

#### List (Sender) vs. Gmail

You are unsubscribing via the list's tools not Gmail's. Whoever manages a list determines:

1. How (or if) you can subscribe to it.
2. Whether unsubscribe links are included in messages.
3. If included, what they actually do, and whether they are formatted in a way that is properly interpreted by Gmail.
4. How (or if) you can resubscribe to the list if you have unsubscribed.

#### Resubscribe

For many one-off lists you would resubscribe in a similar way as you originally subscribed.

For single senders with multiple lists, you might need to access your profile with that sender and change your list preferences.

If you are a member of a Google Group,

1. You can find the email preferences in the main menu under **My membership settings**:
   [image: My membership settings]
2. Then go to the **Subscriptions** section:
   [image: Subscriptions]
3. Configure your preferences:
   [image: Subscriptions preferences]

Comment: Thank you. The unsubscribed email address was set in Google group. I checked the Google group again and found I am still the member there. How to resubscribe?

Comment: @AlpinCleopatra Please [edit] your question to include the info about it being a Google Group subscription as well as a link to the Group for testing purposes.

Comment: I edited the question but I don't know how to add a testing link for Google group.

Comment: @AlpinCleopatra I updated my answer to be more clear and added a Google Groups example. Hope that helps. Here is an example of a link to a Google Group for testing purposes: [groups.google.com/g/tasker](https://groups.google.com/g/tasker)

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks like change from Each email to No email in My membership settings' Subscription is the right solution!